# Insert Bangla language to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating dynamic website with Php and Mysql. So i need insert bangla language to Mysql database. How do i do this with php and mysql ?

**Insert code:**

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_post VALUES ('', '', '$subject', 
'$img','$image_named_uniq','$message','$news_id','$cat_name','', '$poster', '$date' )");
```

Well, if i write English Language then its OK,  But if i write Bangla Language then it's show Something like that ==  &#2477 া&#248 ;&#24 4;&#2480 ; ম& #2494; == Like Html entities...

Or any Idea that will better for me.
Shibbir.

Comment: Well, @Michael Petrotta,  I don't know how do i insert bangla language to mysql database, so that i'm asking.......

Comment: In what way is inserting Bangla text different that inserting text in any other language?

Comment: If i insert bangla text to mysql database then it' show something like that "  &#2477;&#2494;&#2487;&#2494;&#2480; &#2478;&#2494;..."

Comment: Add that, and the code you used to generate that, to your question.

Comment: You may want to google for Unicode and mysql. That will at least give you an idea what kinds of questions to ask. Then there's unicode and php, which is at least as much a challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your encoding of data in your App as well as in DB

have a look at this

[handing uft8 encoding in your App and DB](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 5):

You must add these two lines just after selecting the database, i.e mysqli_connect() function.

mysqli_query($conn,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysqli_query($conn,"SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_general_ci'");

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering after 12 years, hopefully, someone will find it useful! yes, you got that. Those texts are encoded as HTML entities. You really don't need to use UTF-8 Decoding things, that's another stuff! In your case just decode those HTML entities.

By PHP -

```
$str="ম&#2494;ঝ&#2503;মধ&#2509;য&#2503;";
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Output will be -

```
মাঝেমধ্যে
```